# how to display multiple chart on same page in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

Using

```
  using DotNet.Highcharts;
```

Controller Code

```
 //First Part
 Highcharts columnChart = new Highcharts("columnchart");
       ************************
   columnChart.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
   {
       Column =  new PlotOptionsColumn
           {
          DataLabels = new PlotOptionsColumnDataLabels { Enabled = true,
          Crop = true, Overflow = "none",
          Rotation= -50, Padding=200,X=5,Y=-10  }  }
   });
      columnChart.SetXAxis(new XAxis()
        {
            Type = AxisTypes.Category,
            Title = new XAxisTitle() { Text = "Years", Style = "fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '17px'" },
            Categories = tcMX.ToArray()
        });
        columnChart.SetSeries(tcMASt.ToArray());
       **********************
  ViewData["chartYear"]=columnChart;

 //Second Part
  Highcharts columnChartState = new Highcharts("columnchart");
   ************************
       other code same like above
       **********************
   ViewData["chartState"]=columnChartState;
```

cshtml page

```
  @(ViewData["chartYear"])    
  <br/> <br/>
  @(ViewData["chartState"])
```

From above code I have to display both **year wise chart** and **state wise chart**  but only display second chart. if i tried on separate page then it worked fine but when try on same page then only display last chart.

how to solve it?

Comment: Are you putting the charts on the same placeholder (e.g. `<div>` tag)? Try putting in different placeholders, also using different unique ID for both of them.

Comment: I tried both using table and div but not working I think second override first chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're assigning both charts with same name in `Highcharts` initialization constructor, which second chart overrides the first one during rendering inside view as in code below:

```
Highcharts columnChart = new Highcharts("columnchart");

Highcharts columnChartState = new Highcharts("columnchart");
```

Instead, try using different name for second chart (the chart names should be unique to avoid overriding problem):

```
Highcharts columnChartState = new Highcharts("columnchartstate");
```

Also I recommend to strip out `ViewData` usage and put the charts as viewmodel properties with different `<div>` placeholders as in example below:

**Model**

```
public class ChartsViewModel
{
    public Highcharts ColumnChart { get; set; }

    public Highcharts ColumnChartState { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    Highcharts columnChart = new Highcharts("columnchart");
    Highcharts columnChartState = new Highcharts("columnchartstate");

    // other stuff

    var charts = new ChartsViewModel
    {
        ColumnChart = columnChart,
        ColumnChartState = columnChartState
    };

    return View(charts);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ChartsViewModel

<div>@Model.ColumnChart</div>
<br /><br />
<div>@Model.ColumnChartState</div>
```

Reference: [DotNet.Highcharts Class](https://github.com/fairmat/DotNet.Highcharts/blob/master/DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts/Highcharts.cs)